# javascript: return variable from click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
            var n;
            $('ul li').click(function() {
                var n = $(this).index();
            });

            alert(n); // for testing
            currentPage = n;
```

Hello, I want to get `n` out of click function and give this value to the `currentPage`.

**More code:**

```
function reveal(direction) {
    var callbackTime = 750,
        callbackFn = function() {
            var n;
            $('ul li').click(function() {
                var n = $(this).index();
            });
            alert(n); // for testing
            currentPage = n;
            classie.remove(pages[currentPage], 'page--current');
            currentPage = n;
            classie.add(pages[currentPage], 'page--current');
        };
    revealer.reveal(direction, callbackTime, callbackFn);
}
```

Comment: Try this `n = $(this).index();` instead of `var n = $(this).index();`

Comment: For starters, the second `var n` creates a local variable so the outer `var n;` isn't affected. Then there's the fact that `$(this).index()` won't be handled until *after* the rest of the code has run...

Comment: Edit your question to add code rather than posting it in a comment.

Comment: the new code that in  'More code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var n;
$('ul li').click(function() {
    var n = $(this).index();
});  

function reveal(direction) {
    var callbackTime = 750,
        callbackFn = function() {
            classie.remove(pages[currentPage], 'page--current');
            currentPage = n;
            classie.add(pages[currentPage], 'page--current');
        };
    revealer.reveal(direction, callbackTime, callbackFn);
}
```

this is the true solution.

Answer (score 0):

why are you declaring n again?
that should work

```
 var n;
            $('ul li').click(function() {
                n = $(this).index();
            });

            alert(n); // for testing
            currentPage = n;
```

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work? do you have an error or something?

Comment: it is the whole code, when I use the currentPage into click function it work but without effect that I used

Comment: out of function it is working correctly, but into this function, it doesn't.

Comment: can't read your function.. indent it please and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You already defined the var so no need to do it double. Also make sure you have the `$(function() { }` function in your script wich will load the jQuery library:

```
var n = null;
$(function() {
    $('li').on("click", function() {
        n = $(this).index();
    });
});
currentPage = n;
```

To make your code shorter, you can directly assign the `currentPage` var to the `$(this).index()`. *But make sure you have created this variable first, like you did with `n`*